# When redirecting both stdout and stderr to a file, why must the redirection of stderr to stdout come last?

Tags: bash, io-redirection

In order to redirect both stdout and stderr to a file:

```
curl 'https://example.com' > myfile 2>&1
```

This works correctly, but why must the redirection of standard error to standard output be at the very end?

Why can't it be:

```
curl 'https://example.com' 2>&1 > myfile
```

I don't understand why this alternative does not work; it does not redirect stderr to the file. Reading from left to right: "download the web page, redirect stderr to stdout, and redirect stdout to a file", but this is apparently not how Bash interprets the commands. Bash expects `2>&1` to come last. Why must the `2>&1` come last?

Comment: It all comes down to the meaning of "redirect" which is never clearly explained. `>myfile 2>&1` means `fd[1]=open("myfile", write_only); fd[2]=fd[1]`, and `2>&1 >myfile` means `fd[2]=fd[1]; fd[1]=open("myfile", write_only)`. (Simplifying away all the non-essential details). You can easily see that in the latter case, `fd[2]` will not be result of `open("myfile")`, but whatever `fd[1]` was *before* the `fd[1]=open("myfile")` assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trust me, I had this doubt for a long time. Now, I remember it in simple terms.

Here `fd` means `file descriptor`.

In second case `fd2` will point to where ever `fd1` is. And then `fd2` will point to somewhere else.

For sake of understanding consider like it

```
fd1 --> stdout
2>&1, means fd2 --> stdout
then >some_file means fd1 --> some_file
```

So, `fd2` does not follow `fd1`, it follows the target of `fd1`.